# How could I convert a Mobx observable object into a string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using the Mobx to create the observable state.

Here is my code snippet:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(createKey(key), JSON.stringify(state))
```

In the above code the 'state' object is observable. 
When I try to convert it into a string, it gives an error:

> error:Cannot read property 'atom' of undefined

Comment: Could you show us how your state looks? I would suspect you just have to write `state.get()` instead of `JSON.stringify(state)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(mobx.toJS(state))`